# Gitlens hiding the current state of my file?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlens

I was searching for some code in VSCode in a branch that another developer had made, but couldn't find it even though I have their branch and haven't made any changes.

Then I noticed there was a little red triangle in VS Code where their changes should be:

[image: mysterious red triangle]

I opened it and low and behold there code was there:

[image: missing lines of code]

As you can see I haven't made any changes to their branch.

```
git status
On branch feature/featurebranch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/featurebranch'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I have a few extensions installed in VSCode.

[image: VS Code Extensions]

I suspect that GitLens is the culprit.  Is there a configuration that I can make so that it's not hiding code that it actually in the file?  If I open the file in Notepad++ or Notepad it shows the file as it currently is.

```
My VSCode version info is:
Version: 1.74.2 (user setup)
Commit: e8a3071ea4344d9d48ef8a4df2c097372b0c5161
Date: 2022-12-20T10:29:14.590Z
Electron: 19.1.8
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: No
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Why aren't SCM diff decorations showing in the gutter in VS Code 1.76.1?](/q/75715788) Does the issue still reproduce if your roll back to VS Code 1.75.1?

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't look like this is the problem.  I'm running 1.74.2 (added version info to my original post).